# Sitecore instance manager throws error when installing package for training website

Tags: sql, authentication, sitecore

Installing package through Sitecore Instance Manager throws below error when setting up the careers microsite as part of Sitecore Foundations elearning course.

> login failed for user ''

The connection string mentioned in SIM is 
     Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;User ID=sa;Password=****

I am able to successfully login to SQL server using above credentials through Management studio though. I tried to map user sa to the installed core, master, reporting and web sitecore databases and mark it as db_owner but SQL server is not allowing me to do so. What options do I have?

Comment: If you have a Sitecore instance up and running, you can install that package by logging in the Sitecore Desktop mode (Sitecore menu button -> Development Tools -> Installation Wizard).
Make sure that [packagename].zip package is a Sitecore one. You can do that by browsing its content, there must be package.zip file inside.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir. I had to re-install the instance, start  it and then the package installation was successful.